keeping the current element in view when page content re-flows
I have a set of details/summary elements, with a javascript autoclose to keep the page sort - see https://codepen.io/perllaghu/pen/BaXwQOQ as a demonstration.
My problem is that when you have opened an early entry (try 1, 2, or 3) then open a later one (try anything after 4b), the top of the summary data [and thus the focus point] end up off the top of the page.
The jumps are visually worse when the length of the details content varies in length.
Does anyone have a clever way to keep the top of the newly opened item at the cursor point, or at least within the current view-port?

I'm not sure if I got the issue, but you could just give some id and after the click go to the url #id, it should go to the beginning of the text this way

The solution turns out to be nice and obvious [in retrospect]... and tested in Firefox, Chromium, Edge, and Polypane.
pen updated....
I also note that Kevin Powell has published a partially related video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vzj3jSUbMtI
Edit [November 2024]: If you give each detail item the same name attribute, that will auto-close other disclosures in the same "group" - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details#name
